# What is the "digits number"?

Tags: decimal-expansion

I recently took a test asking me what the "digits number" of 17 was. It also asked me this same question for a number like 18471872717171717. What does that mean?

Comment: No idea - I don't think it is a non-standard term. Can you tell us what class this was in?

Comment: could it possible mean `the number of digits`? Then it is $2$ for $17$ and $17$ for the second number

Comment: Never heard that phrase before.  As a wild guess:  sum of the digits?  Perhaps iterated sum of the digits?

Comment: I also never heard that phrase, but my first case is that is a garbled version of "units digit" -- that is, the digit in the "Ones" place, which for both numbers would be 7.

Comment: As the comments make clear, this is not a standard term.  Of course your professor might well have defined it in class (or on the exam itself).  But I think you'll need to get clarity from whomever set the exam.

Comment: Any chance it was the sum of digits?

Comment: This was a GRE question, and I don't know the answer. I'm going to retake it and since I'd never heard this term before, I figured it was important I learn it.
I'll assume they meant units digit next time. If they don't specifically say that, then I'll flip a coin between number of digits and sum of all digits.

Comment: I think that I have once or twice seen the term used to mean the least significant digit of an integer, also known as the units’ digit.